# Why is there no spacing between words in the table of contents?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, copy-paste

When I make a table of contents in LaTeX and execute the TeX File with `pdflatex`, some spaces (the most of them) in it are deleted for search function (and for me in braille).

My question is: why does that happen and how can I solve it?

I use following code (just a snippet):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
% Packages I am going to use
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% Comand ddefinitions
\newcommand*\voordeel{\item[+]}
\newcommand*\nadeel{\item[-]}

% Information of the report
\title{Cursus: Hoe maak ik een goed werkstuk}
\author{Jordy Deweer}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Inleiding}
Here some text for the preface (preface is 'inleiding' in Dutch).

\section]{Ons initiatief}
Some text again, to fill the section. This section is not shown in the table of contennts.

\chapter{De eerste stappen}
Some more text to fill this capter with.

\chapter{Lay-outen van je teksten}
And so on. Complete everithing with your own text, if you need more text!!

\end{document}
```

What's wrong, why do I get this troubles, how can I solve them?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60440/discussion-on-question-by-jordy-deweer-why-is-there-no-spacing-between-words-in).

Comment: @JordyDeweer Minimal non-working example: `\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Ons initiatief}
\end{document}`

Comment: [Useful link](https://superuser.com/a/198395/4272) for questions about spaces in the PDF (and we have many on this site): “PDFs are designed to mimic a printed page, and they are designed *only* as an output format, not an input format. a PDF is basically a map containing the exact location of characters (individual letters or punctuation, etc.) or images. *In most cases*, a PDF does not even store information about where one *word* ends and another begins, much less things like soft breaks vs. hard breaks for paragraph endings.”

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce your problem, so I'm guessing: In pdf's generated by TeX spaces are not space characters or glyphs. There are simply shifts. And so it is up to the pdf viewer and its heuristic to decide if a shift of a glyph is meant as (word)space or not.

You could try to insert real spaces with this code in the preamble:

```
%\pdfmapline{+dummy-space <dummy-space.pfb} %miktex
\pdfglyphtounicode{space}{0020}
\pdfinterwordspaceon
```

If you are using miktex you will have to download dummy-space.tfm and dummy-space.pfb and put them where the system can find them (e.g. for the first tests in the folder of your document). You can find them here

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/doc/pdftex/tests/01-fake-interword-space

Comment: Now, it makes one long line without spaces! (After uncomenting the line with the pdfmapline).

Comment: Sorry it is rather difficult to help you without something to reproduce the problem, I even couldn't download your pdf as onedrive asked for a passport.

Comment: OneDrive asks for a passport??? Wth is happening???
And yes, I understand, I'll live without spaces then hahaha Thanks for the effort!

Comment: Ups. I must have my thoughts somewhere else. I meant a password (it wanted me to login in some account that I don't have).

Comment: Strange... Normally, it should be accessible... Can't you click for "Just download" or something similar?

Comment: No. As I said there is a login page.